# Repeate keyboard macro (e) doesn't work when I ace-jump-window/aw-flip-window to another frame

Tags: keyboard-macros, ace-window

If I use `ace-jump-window`'s `aw-flip-window` functionality in the middle of defining a macro (i.e. switch to the last window - I want which windows I jump between to be dynamic, not fixed to the current window configuration) this generally works, but not when (i) I flip back to the original window and (ii) the window flipped-to is in another frame. The macro still works, no errors occur and `*Messages*` still says `(Type e to repeat macro)`, but this simply results in me entering the letter "e" and I have to `C-x e` again.

To be clear, this works if I do just *one* flip between frames, just not if I then flip back to the original frame.

Any ideas what might be happening, or how to diagnose?

Comment: What happens if you use the built-in commands `select-frame-by-name` (`C-x 5 l` for me) or `other-frame` (`C-x 5 o`) instead of `aw-flip-window`?

Comment: @PhilHudson same behaviour with both `other-frame` and `select-frame-by-name`

Comment: I'm out of ideas for the moment then. Maybe you've found a bug. You've done your duty trying to work it out yourself. Try reporting it to the devs with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Thanks @PhilHudson, I think I'll do that